# Spark Streaming Graceful Shutdown

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I saw there is an option to configure graceful shutdown in two places:

1. While defining spark conf:

> "spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true".

2. When stopping the streaming context:

> JavaStreamingContext scc;
>
> scc.stop(true,true)

What is the differences between the two options?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first way

```
sparkConf.set(“spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true")
```

> Setting this parameter to True in spark configuration ensures the
>   proper graceful shutdown in new Spark version (1.4 onwards)
>   applications. Also we should not use 1st explicit shutdown hook
>   approach or call the `ssc.stop` method in the driver along with this
>   parameter . We can just set this parameter, and then call methods
>   `ssc.start()` and `ssc.awaitTermination()` . No need to call `ssc.stop`
>   method. Otherwise application might hung during shutdown.

The second way 
`scc.stop(true,true)`

> The `scc.stop()` method’s 1st boolean argument is for stopping the
>   associated spark context while the 2nd boolean argument is for
>   graceful shutdown of streaming context

This has been clearly mention [here](http://why-not-learn-something.blogspot.dk/2016/05/apache-spark-streaming-how-to-do.html) by **chandan prakash**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would like to add that to accomplish graceful shutdown when running on yarn, one must provide a mechanism to signal the shutdown.  For instance, spark streaming application should poll for a file, a queue or other source of input and then gracefully stop .

Comment: If i'm running the driver from the master node, I assume I can run SIGTERM for gracefull shutdown?

Comment: Thanks for this.

I added to the sparkConf the graceful statement, but now when I execute SIGTERM on the spark <PID>, the process immediately shuts down, and I get warnings regarding write ahead logs: "exception thrown while writing record: BatchCleanupEvent(ArrayBuffer(1502800045000 ms)) to the WriteAheadLog.

Does it make sense?

Comment: I have never faced the issue . This may help you https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=732763

Comment: so you are telling not to set this parameter spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown when using `scc.stop(true,true)` is it ? @koiralo